# Apache Shiro And Dropwizard Integration

Tags: apache

I am working with Apache Shrino, i want to use authentication and authorization in my application which build with Dropwizard how to Integrate Apache Shrino to my Application.
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

---

there are some integration bundles already available, look at the answer to this [Integrate Apache Shiro Security Library with Dropwizard based JAX-RS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374919/integrate-apache-shiro-security-library-with-dropwizard-based-jax-rs-application)